# Percona xtrabackup Prepare Fails

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona, backup, xtrabackup

I made a backup and according to Percona it completed successfully.  Now I'm trying to prepare it and having the following issue:

```
./xtrabackup_55  --defaults-file="/etc/my.cnf"  --defaults-group="mysqld" --prepare --target-dir=/backup/unprepared/2013_05_21_21_31_41_full
xtrabackup: cd to /backup/unprepared/2013_05_21_21_31_41_full
xtrabackup: This target seems to be not prepared yet.
xtrabackup: No valid checkpoint found.
xtrabackup: Error: xtrabackup_init_temp_log() failed.
```

I've been searching for answers for quite a while and not finding anything conclusive.  Any advice on how to resolve this?

---

Edit: per comment below, here is requested info:

xtrabackup_55 version 2.0.3 for Percona Server 5.5.16 Linux (x86_64) (revision id: 470)

```
cat /etc/my.cnf|grep innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = /data/mysql_data/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/mysql/data/
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 40M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_log_block_size = 512
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_doublewrite_file = /var/mysql/innodb_doublewrite.buff
innodb_flush_method = ALL_O_DIRECT
```

Comment: Can you provide the version of xtrabackup_55 that you're using (`xtrabackup_55 --version`), and any innodb configuration entries from your `my.cnf` file (or the output of `show global variables like 'innodb%';`)?

Comment: [Percona xtrabackup documentation](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/xtrabackup_bin/preparing_the_backup.html?id=percona-xtrabackup:xtrabackup:prepare) indicates that you should point `xtrabackup_55` to the `backup-my.cnf` file taken with your backup, rather than your live my.cnf file. Though if you're doing the prep on the same server as the backup was taken, I'm not sure if it will make a difference.

Comment: Interesting, I switched it to use the backed up my.cnf file (in the backup dir), and now it's doing something :)  Feel free to move that comment to an answer, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Percona xtrabackup documentation](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/xtrabackup_bin/preparing_the_backup.html?id=percona-xtrabackup%3axtrabackup%3aprepare) indicates that you should point `xtrabackup_55` to the `backup-my.cnf` file taken with your backup, rather than your live my.cnf file.

If you're doing the prep on the same server as the backup was taken, I'm not sure if it will make a difference.