# Cannot prepare backup with innobackupex

Tags: backup, restore, percona

I taken full backup from a Master server with innobackupex.

Now I am restoring backup with `innobackupex` on a Slave server.

I prepare backup with the command:

```
innobackupex --defaults-file=/var/lib/mysql/backup-my.cnf --apply-log /var/lib/mysql
```

This command end up with messages:

```
xtrabackup: cd to /var/lib/mysql/
xtrabackup: This target seems to be not prepared yet.
xtrabackup: No valid checkpoint found.
xtrabackup: Error: xtrabackup_init_temp_log() failed.
```

What do I need to do to get rid of these messages and restore my backup?

I use innobackupex version 2.3.10 and percona server 5.7.35.

I have seen [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42855/percona-xtrabackup-prepare-fails) question, but its answer did not help me.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. According to the [official documentation](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/creating_a_backup_ibk.html#:~:text=innobackupex%3A%20Backup%20created%20in%20directory%20%27/path/to/BACKUP-DIR/2013-03-25_00-00-09%27%0Ainnobackupex%3A%20MySQL%20binlog%20position%3A%20filename%20%27mysql-bin.000003%27%2C%20position%201946%0A111225%2000%3A00%3A53%20%20innobackupex%3A%20completed%20OK!) you should have received an OK message at the end of the backup. Did you receive an OK message?

Comment: No, I did not receive an OK message

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there are different versions of innobackupex on Master and Slave servers. That caused the problem.
After installing same innobackupex version on slave I successfully prepared the backup and got "completed OK!" message.